# Rails 3 create to Rails4 strong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I was transforming my Rails 3 project to Rails4, but I am confused about `strong parameter`.

Here is the original code in `Rails 3`

```
series_mission = SeriesMission.create({name: params[:name], mode: Mission.mode_mapping(params[:mode].to_s), start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time, gamecharacter_id: gc.id}, :without_protection => true)
```

It works fine. But it's wrong after I modified into this way in `Rails 4`.

```
attrs = { name: params[:name], mode: Mission.mode_mapping(params[:mode].to_s), start_time: start_time,
     end_time: end_time, gamecharacter_id: gc.id }
attrs = attrs.require(:series_mission).permit(:name, :mode, :start_time, :end_time, :gamecharacter_id)
series_mission = SeriesMission.create(attrs)
```

It threw this error

```
private method `require' called for #<Hash:0x007fd2a421e8b8>
```

### Update

```
qset_ids = params[:sub_missions]
start_time = ((t = params[:start_time].to_i) == 0 ? nil : Time.at(t))
end_time = ((t = params[:end_time].to_i) == 0 ? nil : Time.at(t))
```

Only `gamecharacter_id` is not passing by `params`

Comment: You are just taking `:name` from `params` where are other values coming from?

Comment: please add the code

Comment: And FYI you can call `require` on params not on hash

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of strong parameters. They are for **whitelisting** incoming data. But since you *already* do that (by building that hash), you don't need strong params.

```
attrs = { name: params[:name], mode: Mission.mode_mapping(params[:mode].to_s), start_time: start_time,
     end_time: end_time, gamecharacter_id: gc.id }
series_mission = SeriesMission.create(attrs)
```

#### What do you mean, whitelisting?

Imagine that you have a profile edit page. There you can change a name and a picture. Some users in your app can be admins. This status is controlled by a boolean column in the db, `is_admin`. Naturally, you can't make user an admin through that profile edit UI, because there's no checkbox for it. However, a malicious user can forge requests however they like and send data as if *there was* such checkbox. And you would blindly accept it and make them admins.

With strong params, you *whitelist* data you want to process

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :picture)
```

Here, even if `is_admin` param was present in the request, it would be discarded and not used in the update operation.

As you can see, code in your question doesn't suffer from this, because there is "natural" whitelisting.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question. Only `gamecharacter_id` is not coming from `params`

Comment: @CodaChang: doesn't change anything. Did you read the answer?

Comment: Yes, I've read the answer. I just want to make sure. Thank for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Strong params is only used for mass-assignment. Seeing as you are manually passing in each individual attribute you don't need to use strong params at all. This will work:

```
attrs = { name: params[:name], mode: Mission.mode_mapping(params[:mode].to_s), start_time: start_time,
 end_time: end_time, gamecharacter_id: gc.id }

series_mission = SeriesMission.create(attrs)
```